# post to django API returns 403 (Forbidden) when authenticated, but able post when not authenticated

Tags: django, fetch

I'm building an app that works as follows:

- Users fill out data on an html form and submit.
- the data is posted onto the API (via Fetch).

This app uses django, django rest frame work with plain html and vanilla jav
My issue is that when the user is authenticated on the API/backend, I cannot post. It returns 403. However, when I am not authenticated I can post data from the form.

Here is the JS on the form.html that posts data into the API:

```
<script>
  console.log('js linked')
  function getCookie(name) {
      var cookieValue = null;
      if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
          var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
          for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
              var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
              // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
              if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                  cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
      return cookieValue;
  }
  var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

console.log(csrftoken)

  function post_report(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var contact_email = document.getElementById("contact_email").value
    var contact_number = document.getElementById("contact_number").value
    var date_time = document.getElementById("date_time").value
    var location = document.getElementById("location").value
    var description = document.getElementById("description").value
    console.log(contact_email + ' ' + description)


    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Flight_Safety_Reports/",{
      method: "POST",
      mode: 'same-origin',
      headers:{
        "Accept": "application/json",
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        contact_email:contact_email,
        contact_number:contact_number,
        date_time:date_time,
        location:location,
        description:description

      })
    })
    .then(response =>console.log(response))

    alert('report submitted')

  }

</script>
```

views.py

```
from app_reports.models import (
FlightSafetyReport
)

from .serializers import (
FlightSafetyReportSerializer
)

class FlightSafetyReportViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = FlightSafetyReportSerializer
    queryset = FlightSafetyReport.objects.all()
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'bootstrap4',

    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'articles',
    'user_api',
    'app_sandbox',


    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djreact.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BUILD_DIR, BACKEND_TEMPLATES_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djreact.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
   'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
]
}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True


STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BUILD_DIR,'static')]


CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XSRF-TOKEN"
```

To re-iterate, when I am not logged into the api / when I am not logged into django-admin I am able to post. When I am logged in, I get a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: Have you tried using ```$.ajax()```. I had this problem with fetch. I found when I was posting data using ```fetch``` I was not authenticated but when I used ```$.ajax()``` it authenticated me.

Comment: I just tried ajax (and axios). both them returned a 403 error when I am authenticated. When I am not authenticated, ajax returned 400, indicating it can post, but the data was not correct. Axios returned 403. I won't continue with ajax because if the code was correct and had a proper request, it would still return 403 error when authenticated.

Comment: How do you authenticate to the backend. Do you use the ```api-auth/``` endpoint?

Comment: I use rest-auth.urls

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is what I I think is happening to your requests. The problem might be that you are passing an invalid csrftoken. I have created a duplicate of your code on my side and it works. It starts giving me `403` error when I change csrftoken value to some random value. Like below check it out.

```
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    csrftoken = "blacjcjsjsjss";
```

It then gives the 403 Forbidden error in the console. If I remove the line `csrftoken = "blacjcjsjsjss";` it starts working again. What I am saying is that your csrftoken value is some how wrong. You need to make sure that you are getting the correct crsftoken.

Comment: Interesting. Could that mean that there's some wierd interaction between this csrftoken being authenticated?

Comment: I found the problem. It's in your settings.py file. In your settings.py file you have given the csrf cookie name to be ```XSRF-TOKEN``` here ```CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XSRF-TOKEN"```. In your javascript your are accessing it using the wrong name here ```var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');```. You should use the name you specified in your settings.py, here ```var csrftoken = getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');```. That's why you are getting ```403``` it's becuase your csrftoken is invalid.